# select distinct records

Tags: sql, firebird

[image: data grig]

I have a table like as shown above. As you can see that value in the "v_ctra_no" column repeats. What type of sql query should I use so that I am able to select those rows whose "v_ctra_no" value is unique. Like for example

```
col_name1      col_name2     col_name3
Ctra#001        Cash            200
Ctra#002        Sales           40
Ctra#003        Purchase        1000
```

I tried to use the query mentioned below but it does not work

```
SELECT DISTINCT(v_ctra_no),v_ctra_date,v_ctra_id FROM TBL_ACC_CTRA_VCH_MSB
```

Comment: In your example nothing repeats and the column names do not match your description.

Comment: Have you seen the image of my table that i have included with this question??? Please see the image link above

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows. I.e `SELECT distinct(c1), c2` eq. `SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2` eq. `SELECT DISTINCT c1, (c2)`.

Comment: It seems that `v_ctra_id` is the unique identifier for the table. In this case, your `DISTINCT` command will have no effect.

Comment: Hmm..Then how do i select those rows having unique v_ctra_no???any suggestions?

Comment: @msm What exactly are you trying to achieve? The fields `Cash`/`Sales`/`Purchase` that you mention, are they going to be unique for each `v_ctra_no`? It looks like from your table that there are multiple options for each `v_ctra_no` record. And the numbers in `col_name3`, what do they represent? It looks like the total of all sales, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to sum up the sales amounts. Seems that this is more what you are looking for:

```
SELECT v_ctra_no, v_ctra_dr_ledgeacc_name, SUM(v_ctra_dr_ledgeacc_amt) AS v_total_sales
FROM TBL_ACC_CTRA_VCH_MSB
GROUP BY v_ctra_no, v_ctra_dr_ledgeacc_name
```

This will show the account number and account name, along with the total (SUM) of all of the entries in the account amount column. As long as the account name is the same for all of the account number entries, then you won't have any duplicates.

However, you may want to consider restructuring your database (if you have that option), so that account details are separate to the separate sales amounts.

If you don't want the sales information and just want the account details along with the dates, then you can do a distinct on the name like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v_ctra_no, v_ctra_date
FROM TBL_ACC_CTRA_VCH_MSB
```

However, you will get duplicates for each time the date is different but the account number stays the same. If you think about it for a bit, it makes sense.

If you just want the distinct account numbers, then just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v_ctra_no
FROM TBL_ACC_CTRA_VCH_MSB
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Actually i need the above query to populate a ListView with columns 'v_ctra_no' and 'v_ctra_date' in the front-end interface and not to sum up sales amount.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous then, as you are listing the values in `col_name3` which appear to be numbers.